# JS var declaring - Wrong validation due to function problem with variable holding same value

Tags: javascript, function, preventdefault

I am doing a Validation for Form "Text input".
If the user leaves the input empty, a function is starting to run. If the field is bigger than 1 - so it doesn't get into the function.

The problem is:
The first time, the user left the input empty, function ran, and I got the alert - that's OK.
Second time, The user added 10 in the AGE input - And again he gets the Alert - But he should not.

Note:
Age input value, returns from a different function (calc) to a var called: result.

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn_send').click(function(){
    //var result gets the value ffrom another function of input "Age" value. -> return thisform.Age.value
    var result = calc(document.getElementById("campaignform")); 
        if (result<1)
        {
            $("#campaignform").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); alert ("prevent default");
            });
        }
        else{
        return true;
        };
});
```

});

so if you try the second time to click on Submit, then you get into $('#btn_send').click(function() and eventhough you added for example 67 in the AGE (return as result) input, you get into the IF atatement which is:  if (result<1)

I'm pretty new to developing, so I hop you will understand me.
Sorry if I have mistakes.
Can you advice what could be a better TITLE for this question?

thanks in advance,
Shai

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#campaignform").submit(function(event) {
```

Adds an event handler to the form so that every time it gets submitted in future, the function gets called. You never remove that event handler again, so even after the field is corrected the default-preventing function will still get called on every submit.

jQuery event handlers can be removed using the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method, but generally it's better to avoid lots of adding and removing handlers. Easier—and also more reliable, since catching button clicks can fail to pick up all form submissions—is to do everything in one static `submit` event handler, eg:

```
$('#campaignform').submit(function(ev){
    var result= calc(this);
    if (result<1) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        alert('prevent default');
    }
});
```